# Different color for rows in table

Tags: css, css-tables

It's possible to create something like this only through table CSS style?
I can create different color for even and odd rows, but I would like to create this (just the colors):

[image: example]

Comment: So, what is the logic on this coloring?

Comment: Looks like it's related to the first character of the first column. I'd say just create a CSS class for each one of those with the appropriate background color, and tag the row with that class is easiest.

Comment: You could use nth-child to target each tr, then last child to target last elements. If you don't care for semantic markup - you could just add a class to those red tds.

Comment: @LcSalazar
I need to create well-aranged table

Comment: @JoeMcMahon
I can't use rows styling, i can create css style only for table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of rows is constant, you can use `nth-of-type`, `nth-last-of-type`, or `nth-child` selectors plus the formulae, to make the coloring work.  This example also requires to play with selector specificity by placing rule sets in a particular order: http://jsfiddle.net/se4Lwt1y/.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 21</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(-n + 11) {
    background-color: hsla(60, 70%, 70%, 1);
}

table tr:nth-of-type(-n + 3) {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 70%, 1);
}

table tr:nth-last-of-type(-n + 11) {
    background-color: hsla(200, 50%, 70%, 1);
}

table tr:nth-last-of-type(-n + 4) {
    background-color: hsla(200, 50%, 60%, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it could work. I'll try it soon and post the result